# Accessing subclass specific methods with superclass object without type casting in Java

Tags: java, casting, subclass

I have an interface representing a Chess piece and a bunch of classes for the specific pieces inheriting the Chess piece interface. These classes share a lot of methods like move or capture, but many also have piece-specific methods like promotions with pawns and what not.

I know I can type cast the superclass object into the subclass and call subclass specific methods like so:

```
Piece piece = new Pawn();
((Pawn)piece).pawnSpecifcMethod();
```

... but I was told that casting in Java is bad practice as it causes run-time errors. Is there a better way to design my class structure so that I can have the benefits of having an interface without all this pesky type casting trickiness?

Thanks in advance from a Java beginner :(

Comment: Hey! Could you show an exact use case? In general, I wouldn't call that bad practice per se, you just never should "auto-use" it and you can be sure that most of the time there is a better solution for the case. Btw. I think a chess piece should be an abstract class, not an interface.

Comment: The problem with downcasting is you need to know what to downcast to.  Not all pieces are pawns.  And I would try and stay away from `specific methods`  Have a move method in an abstract class and override it for the particular piece.  And have a `canPromote` method, and so on.  Try to keep the method names piece independent.

Comment: @WJS Is it okay to have a lot of "dead" methods in my other classes? If I had a bunch of subclass-specific methods, would this not result in a bunch of functions in subclasses that don't do anything?

Comment: "I was told that casting in Java is bad practice as it causes run-time errors" That's wrong that general. There can be good reasons to have `pawnSpecifcMethod`. But of course you should check if your `Piece` is a `Pawn` before casting: `if (piece instanceof Pawn) ((Pawn)piece).pawnSpecifcMethod();`. So the casting cannot causing run-time error.

Comment: @AxelRichter Ah so assuming that I was using it in a case where I knew for certain that piece was of type pawn / checked before that it was of type pawn, casting can be considered a best practice?

Comment: There is not always **the** best practice solution. But casting is part of `Java` language. So it cannot be bad practice if it is used correctly.

Comment: The general principle is that _if you know that you need a `Pawn`_, then (consistently) treat the object as a `Pawn` in the first place. Many times, you just need to know that you have "some quantity of objects"; in that case a `Collection` is suitable. But if you know that you need a `SortedSet`, then you declare that requirement.